# Reading Attribute of .xml Tag Gives NoType

Tags: python, xml

I have an .xml file that looks like this:

```
<parking id="pucpr">
  <space id="1" occupied="1">
    <rotatedRect>
      <center x="300" y="207" />
      <size w="55" h="32" />
      <angle d="-74" />
    </rotatedRect>
    <contour>
      <point x="278" y="230" />
      <point x="290" y="186" />
      <point x="324" y="185" />
      <point x="308" y="230" />
    </contour>
  </space>
.
.
.
```

To read the values of `center`, `size` and `angle`, my code looks as follows:

```
def extract_boxes(filename):
        tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        boxes = list()
        # For every space in the spaces
        for space in root.findall('.//space'):
            box_class_list = list()
            centerCoor = list()
            sizeVals = list()
            degreeVal = 0
            classification = 0
            # Getting center
            for centerPoints in space.findall('rotatedRect/center'):
                centerCoor.append(int(centerPoints.get('x')))
                centerCoor.append(int(centerPoints.get('y')))
            # Getting width and height
            for sizePoints in space.findall('rotatedRect/size'):
                sizeVals.append(int(sizePoints.get('w')))
                sizeVals.append(int(sizePoints.get('h')))
            # Getting the angle
            for degree in space.findall('rotatedRect/angle'):
                degreeVal = int(degree.get('d'))
            print(centerCoor)
            print(sizeVals)
            print(degreeVal)

            # topleft - [center_x - width, center_y - height]
            pt1 = [centerCoor[0] - sizeVals[0], centerCoor[1] - sizeVals[1]]
            # btmleft - [center_x - width, center_y + height]
            pt2 = [centerCoor[0] - sizeVals[0], centerCoor[1] + sizeVals[1]]
            # btmright - [center_x + width, center_y + height]
            pt3 = [centerCoor[0] + sizeVals[0], centerCoor[1] + sizeVals[1]]
            # topright - [center_x + width, center_y - height]
            pt4 = [centerCoor[0] + sizeVals[0], centerCoor[1] - sizeVals[1]]

            rectangle = [pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt1]

            rectangle_rotated = [
                rotate(centerCoor, pt,  math.radians(degreeVal)) for pt in rectangle]

            rectangle = np.array(rectangle)
            rectangle_rotated = np.array(rectangle_rotated)

            # Finally, the actual x_min, x_max and such, needed for bounding box
            x_min, y_min = np.min(rectangle_rotated, axis=0)
            x_max, y_max = np.max(rectangle_rotated, axis=0)

            coors = [x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]

            box_class_list.append(coors)

            # Get the name or classification of the class corresponding to the box
            classification = int(space.get('occupied'))

            box_class_list.append(classification)

            boxes.append(box_class_list)
            #print(boxes)

        width = 1280
        height = 720

        return boxes, width, height
```

My problem is in line:

```
# Get the name or classification of the class corresponding to the box
            classification = int(space.get('occupied'))
```

For some reason, I keep getting the error:
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

If I do: `classification = int(space.attrib['occupied'])`, I get `KeyError: 'occupied'`

I'm not exactly sure how to access the tag at this point.

Comment: Are you sure that every `space` element has the attribute you are looking for?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get the "occupied" value from <space id="1" occupied="1">, is that not it?

Comment: See my answer - it works on dummy input.

Answer (score 0):

The below works... so you must be missing something

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<parking id="pucpr">
  <space id="1" occupied="1">
    <rotatedRect>
      <center x="300" y="207" />
      <size w="55" h="32" />
      <angle d="-74" />
    </rotatedRect>
    <contour>
      <point x="278" y="230" />
      <point x="290" y="186" />
      <point x="324" y="185" />
      <point x="308" y="230" />
    </contour>
  </space>
    <space id="1" occupied="99">
    <rotatedRect>
      <center x="300" y="207" />
      <size w="55" h="32" />
      <angle d="-74" />
    </rotatedRect>
    <contour>
      <point x="278" y="230" />
      <point x="290" y="186" />
      <point x="324" y="185" />
      <point x="308" y="230" />
    </contour>
  </space>
  </parking>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
spaces = root.findall('.//space')
for space in spaces:
    print(f'classification: {int(space.attrib["occupied"])}')
```

output

```
classification: 1
classification: 99
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not on PC currently, but I'll plug and see tomorrow!